# Cannot use input methods (iBus/fcitx) in WINE apps

Tags: wine, ibus, input, xterm, fcitx

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and KDE Plasma 5.18.8.

Recently, I installed WeChat on Crossover 21 and found that I cannot input Chinese characters using iBus input method. When I click the text entry field and start typing, the candidate window doesn't show up so I can only input English, even if I have switched iBus keyboard from English to Chinese Pinyin.

At the beginning I thought it was WeChat's fault, but then I tried notepad.exe in WINE and it doesn't work either. Chinese characters can be displayed correctly in notepad.exe, so I guess there's nothing wrong with my locale settings. Pasting Chinese characters from other apps is also OK, but I just can't use any input methods.

iBus works well in other applications but only does not work in any WINE applications. I have tested iBus in Crossover, wine and deepin-wine, but none of them works well with iBus. I have also tried to use fcitx but it doesn't work either. I suppose maybe my input methods cannot detect text entry fields in WINE apps so they won't activate when type into these fields.

Besides, I have tried some methods that I found on Google, like adding

```
export LC_ALL=zh_CN.UTF-8
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

to my `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/profile` and `~/.xprofile`.  But sadly it makes no difference to me :(

I'd be glad if anyone can help me with this problem. Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT** 28 Mar.

I installed a new Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a virtual machine and tested typing with iBus in Wine 6.0, worked fine. So I can confirm that it is not caused by a bug in wine.

Reinstalling ubuntu can solve this problem, but it is a last resort for me since I have configured many packages and envs and don't wanna spend so much time on reinstalling them.

Comment: Hello. Have you checked the Wine site to see if the app even supports what you want to do under Wine? Not all apps or all features of the apps it does support will work. Wine also has its own support forum.

Comment: @David Hi David, I had searched on WineHQ forum and found it was a bug in Wine 4.17 that Chinese input methods were unable to use. [Bug 47821](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47821). However this bug has already been fixed in 4.19 so it's rarely discussed after that. It's really strange that I come across this problem in my wine 6.0 so I wonder if I got some configures or packages wrong in my ubuntu so wine does not work well.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem,  my enviroment is
OS: ubuntu20.04
wine: wine-8.0.2

I tried two wine variations, such as uklyin-wine, official wine-8.0.2, wechat can be installed successfuly, but only only English  can be used, other inputs methods provided by under ibus and fcitx frame  are ignored
that means wine application failed to connect with ibus and fcitx